# How Would You Generate Hash with Nested Attributes for Rspec Controller #create Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec2, rspec-rails

I am testing Rails 4 controller `#create` action in Rspec as following:

```
describe "POST #create" do    
    it "saves personality test responses in database" do
      expect {
        post :create, graduate_id: graduate, personality_test: attributes_for(...)
      }.to change(PersonalityTest, :count).by(1)
    end
end
```

Note, the `attributes_for(...)` above is the part I am struggling with. In order for the controller to create a new record, I need to pass a hash in this format (where `"personality_test_template_question_id"` and `"personality_test_template_answer_id"` are foreign keys to existing models:

```
"personality_test"=>{
  "personality_test_template_id"=>"1", "personality_test_responses_attributes"=>{
    "0"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"1", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"2"}, 
    "1"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"2", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"9"}, 
    "2"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"3", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"14"}, 
    "3"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"4", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"21"}, 
    "4"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"5", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"27"}, 
    "5"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"6", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"33"}, 
    "6"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"7", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"38"}, 
    "7"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"8", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"46"}, 
    "8"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"9", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"54"}, 
    "9"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"10", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"58"}, 
    "10"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"11", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"64"}, 
    "11"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"12", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"70"}, 
    "12"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"13", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"76"}, 
    "13"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"14", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"83"}, 
    "14"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"15", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"86"}, 
    "15"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"16", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"92"}, 
    "16"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"17", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"101"}, 
    "17"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"18", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"107"}, 
    "18"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"19", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"110"}, 
    "19"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"20", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"119"}, 
    "20"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"21", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"122"}, 
    "21"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"22", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"132"}, 
    "22"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"23", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"137"}, 
    "23"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"24", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"140"}, 
    "24"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"25", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"146"}, 
    "25"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"26", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"152"}, 
    "26"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"27", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"162"}, 
    "27"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"28", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"165"}, 
    "28"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"29", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"173"}, 
    "29"=>{"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"30", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"177"}
  }
}
```

I am not clear what would be the proper way to generate a hash in such format. I've tried FactoryGirl `attributes_for` method, but it doesn't generate attributes for the nested factories. Any tips will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this type of hash format by manually assembling attributes as following:

```
describe "POST #create" do
  let(:valid_attributes) do
    attributes_for(:personality_test).merge(personality_test_template_id: 1,
      personality_test_responses_attributes: attributes_for_list(:personality_test_response, 30) 
    ) 
  end

  it "saves personality test responses in database" do
    expect{ 
      post :create, graduate_id: graduate, personality_test: valid_attributes 
    }.to change(PersonalityTest, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

These are my factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :personality_test do 
    ignore do
      questions_count 30
    end

    after(:build) do |pt, evaluator|
      pt.personality_test_template = PersonalityTestTemplate.find(1)
      pt.personality_test_responses = build_list(:personality_test_response, 
        evaluator.questions_count, personality_test: pt)
    end

  end

  factory :personality_test_response do
    personality_test
    sequence(:personality_test_template_question_id)
    sequence(:personality_test_template_answer_id, 1) { |n| n*6-3}
  end
end
```

Please note, that in this case the parameter hash coming in the request header from RSpec slightly differs from the original one coming from the app view itself in a sense, that RSpec doesn't generate a pseudo-array (e.g. `{ "0" => {...}, "1"=> {...}... }`) for nested attributes. Instead, it generates a regular array of hash attributess and it still works the same. This is what I get from RSpec:

```
"personality_test"=>{
  "personality_test_template_id"=>"1", "personality_test_responses_attributes"=>[
    {"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"1", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"3"}, 
    {"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"2", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"9"}, 
    ... (skipped for brevity)
    {"personality_test_template_question_id"=>"30", "personality_test_template_answer_id"=>"177"}
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps someone.